# Get result.insertId from callback function in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

**Check my updated answer below the other answers. The question turned out to be quite simple, I just didn't understand how async worked or should be handled at the time of posting it**

I have the following code:

```
function qcallb(err,result){
  console.log("result.insertID:"+result.insertId);
  return result.insertId;
}

var createRecord= function (tableName,record){
  try{
    queryStatment="INSERT INTO " + tableName + " SET ?";    
    var result='';
    var query = connection.query(queryStatment, record, qcallb,false);  
  }
  catch(err){
    return 0;
  }
  return iid;
}
```

I want to return the variable `result.insertId` from the callback function, to the function that calls create record, but I have not found a way to do this.

I tried to set a global variable in the callback function, but when I try to access it, its value is still unchanged.

Is there a way for me to either access the value directly in the callback function, or to have callback function notify me when it's called then return the value?

> > > EDIT:
> > >
> > > ### After testing every proposed solution here, and those that I found by searching elsewhere, the only thing that worked for me (without using external modules to make a piece of code run in 'sync' rather than 'async'), was to implement the logic I wanted inside the callback itself, which is what I wanted to avoid in the first place, but I couldn't work around it no matter what I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 years later:

After getting much more experience with node.js and async code, I see how naive this question was, although it was beyond me at the time, which is also obvious in my using a try/catch block around an async call which is useless with async code, where handling errors is done by checking for `err` in the callback and acting upon it if it exists.

Since it seems to have quite a number of views, this seems to be a recurring issue for those newly introduced to async development.

This can't be done in the sense that was asked in the question, for an operation to occur after an async operation and use a value that is a result of the async operation, it has to be called from the callback of the async operation with that value.

To resolve the issue, the code can be modified to:

```
function doSomethingWithResult(result) {
  // query is done, and this would only be called if no error occurred
  console.log('Result is: ', result)
  // do whatever you want
}

function queryCallback(err,result) {
  if (err) {
    throw err
  }

  doSomethingWithResult(result)      
}

function createRecord(tableName, record) {
  queryStatment='INSERT INTO `' + tableName + '` SET ?'

  connection.query(queryStatment, record, queryCallback) 
}
```

### ---

Old Answer: After testing every proposed solution here, and those that I found by searching elsewhere, the only thing that worked for me (without using external modules to make a piece of code run in 'sync' rather than 'async'), was to implement the logic I wanted inside the callback itself, which is what I wanted to avoid in the first place, but I couldn't work around it no matter what I did.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 'notify me' is the way to go:

```
var createRecord= function (tableName,record, cb){
  var query = "INSERT INTO " + connection.escape(tableName) + " SET ?";
  connection.query(query, record, function(err, res) {
    if (err) return cb(err);
    cb(null, res.insertId); // this is "notify me" part
  });  
}

// now use it

createRecord('blah', { foo: "bar" }, function(err, id) {
  console.log(id);
});
```

Also, try/catch won't help much here as callback function is not executed down stack frame but called outside from event loop. You need to use domains/[zones](http://strongloop.com/strongblog/announcing-zones-for-node-js/) or some similar sort of async error handling

Comment: I did the following:

    `db.createRecord(tname, nd, function(err, id) {`
      `console.log("insertId: " +id);`
      `prjid=id;`
    `});`

in a file where I use the file referred to in the OP as my `db` module, and it still gives me an `undefined` when I print the `id` variable.

Is there something that I missed?

Answer (score 0):

i think there is a way with waiting for the response with an endless loop, maybe you can also use the context to assign the variable like so :

```
var sleep = require('sleep');

var createRecord= function (tableName,record){
  try{
    queryStatment="INSERT INTO " + tableName + " SET ?";    
    var insertId=0;
    var query = connection.query(queryStatment, record, function(err,result){
      console.log("result.insertID:"+result.insertId);
      insertId = result.insertId;
    },false);  
  }
  catch(err){
    return 0;
  }
  while(insertId==0){
    sleep.sleep(0.1); # sleep for 0.1 second
  }
  return insertId;
}
```

i haven't tested this code on my machine, please test it and let me know if there is any error.

Comment: I had thought of this method previously, but I thought it was also not a very efficient way to do it, and that's why I asked the question. 

Also, when I tried the code, it didn't work, and I had to change the number of seconds to "1" (apparently it doesn't handle fractions of a second), this allowed the code to run, but it never returned a value! I think it got stuck in the loop for some reason!

Do you think that - if we fix the stuck loop - this would be the only way to do it?

Comment: Try moving `var insertId=0` just before `try` I think this would fix the stuck loop, and no this isn't the only way to do it, you can use a sync module for nodejs, maybe you can use a database sync driver instead of the acync one, but as nodejs isn't my day-to-day language  I can't tell the best solution thought.

Comment: It still gets stuck even when I moved the `var insertId=0` before the `try`. I guess I should look for a sync driver as you suggested. If you have any other suggestions, please let me know. Thanks for your help :)